# How can I store an array in a variable using a FOR with TypeScript?

Tags: angular

Hello friends I need your help with a solution I describe the context.

- We have the **ress** array is bounded only with those that match the condition

[image: Code + Printing]

- Once this is done I need to save the array results in a new variable, I tried several ways but it didn't work.

`this.listavacacionesAcot[i] = ress[i]`

[image: Enter code, result]

I hope as a result

`this.listavacacionesAcot = [`
`{data},`
`{data},`
`{data}`
`]`

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition

```
this.listavacacionesAcot.push(ress[i])
```

remove lines 156, 166

Comment: I get this error 
-----
react_devtools_backend.js:3973 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at SafeSubscriber._next (modulo-consulta.component.ts:160:40)

Comment: @Agustìn Arenas How is the listavacacionesAcot instantiated in the component?

Comment: Yes you must instantiate the array at the class level as empty, see Pranav's comment

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
The variable is modified, remaining from ListavacacionesAcot; to

```
listavacacionesAcot=[]
```

I take into account Garrett Witzenburg's comment

```
this.listavacacionesAcot.push(ress[i])
```

[image: Solución]

Research source
[enter link description here](https://techstrology.com/cannot-read-a-property-push-of-undefined-in-angular/)